# Uninstalled Python from Ubuntu and removed environment variables as well, how do I fix it?

Tags: python, ubuntu, dependencies

Ok, I know what I have done is very stupid. But it's done.
There was an version mismatch in my app and these are the commands I fired:
`sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove python*`

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/lib/python* 
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/python* sudo
rm -rf /usr/bin/py* sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/py* sudo rm -rf
/usr/include/python*
```

Now, I have tried everything I could find on the internet. The error I'm getting with almost any installation is this:

```
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
Python path configuration:
  PYTHONHOME = (not set)
  PYTHONPATH = (not set)
  program name = '/usr/bin/python3.10'
  isolated = 0
  environment = 0
  user site = 1
  import site = 0
  sys._base_executable = '/usr/bin/python3.10'
  sys.base_prefix = '/usr'
  sys.base_exec_prefix = '/usr'
  sys.executable = '/usr/bin/python3.10'
  sys.prefix = '/usr'
  sys.exec_prefix = '/usr'
  sys.path = [
    '/usr/lib/python10.zip',
    '/usr/lib/python3.10',
    '/usr/lib/lib-dynload',
  ]
Fatal Python error: init_fs_encoding: failed to get the Python codec of the filesystem encoding
Python runtime state: core initialized
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x00007f44dad8e740 (most recent call first):
<no Python frame>
```

If I try to install ubuntu-desktop, same error. If i try to install python3-encoding, same error. It's the same with everything.
How do I fix this??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried installing Python again? `sudo apt-get install python3` or such?

Comment: I did this once and it is pretty much unrecoverable unless you want to delve into the Linux kernel itself. Your best bet is to save your necessary files into a USB drive and reinstall the OS.

Comment: @Robert i tried, but it doesn't work since it has no usable python installed.

Comment: @SimonUnderwood I think you're right. I can't even get my UI to work, so even creating backup is a hassle.

Comment: So what did you do finally? Reinstalled ubuntu? Even i am stuck with this no apt command works.